# Difference in including the .cpp file and .h file (with the same content in cpp)?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I've recently started learning cpp from basics and was very much confused with the folowing:

Lets say I have a header( `test.h` which contains only declarations) with some content and some source file (`source.cpp`) and program produced some result.

If I have copied the same content of that header file to a .cpp file (`testcpp.cpp`) and included this in `source.cpp`

In this case, I did not understood what difference it makes?

(**I'll not include this `testcpp.cpp` in make file**)

I have seen some threads similar to this but couldn't get a clear idea!!!

***I learnt the usage of header and cpp files and have used it correctly in projects till now, Please answer specific to this scenario (I know doing this way adds confusion but just want to know). Will there be any difference doing so or it's just a common practice everyone follows ?***

Comment: Source files are not for including.  You should basically never include a source file.  Instead you should compile it into an object file and link it to your other object files to make the executable.

Comment: @NathanOliver, I agree!!! I followed this till now. But just want to know will there be any difference doing the same with a file named `.cpp` rather than `.h`

Comment: `#include "whatever"` works as "copy all text from file `whatever` here".

Comment: @infiniteloop `#include` doesn't care about the file type, it will do the same thing regarless.

Comment: @NathanOliver and VTT this is interesting to know. From what I've learnt till now, I dont know what you guys mentioned

Comment: In that case Can I add anything(file with any extension) to the make file with a proper cpp code?

Comment: Assuming your header file contains only declarations and all your definitions are in a source file, there is a difference. You must never provide more than one definition for a function. By including a source file, you run the risk of including it twice (a second time in another file), which will cause your linking to fail. Multiple declarations are fine, which is why you can include headers as you please.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Yeah I know this, even keeping the definition in header file and including the header in more than 1 source file does the same ryt!!

Comment: @infiniteloop No, you can include a header as often as you want and it's fine (if ti only contains declarations). Multiple declarations is allowed, as long as each declaration is identical (which it is if you are including the same file each time).

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux, I've commented that if the header also contains definition (which is not preferred but is allowed), In that case it would be the same ryt!!!

Comment: What does "same ryt" mean?

Comment: @infiniteloop Yes, but then it wouldn't be a header anymore, it would be a source file. A header is assumed to be a file you can freely include. Note that there are some exceptions where it's fine to include implementation in a header, such as `inline` and template function definitions. See [ODR](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition#One_Definition_Rule).

Comment: I guess there would be no difference if the header also contains definition (not only declaration). Including such header also causes multiple definition while linking. Its just with what (code inside file) we are including rather than .h or .cpp

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux, Got the term `header` now. Apologies if my earlier ques were irritating.

Comment: not advisable to include .c or .cpp files in the header, could lead to lost of mysterious compile errors. am talking out of experience, same advice i received.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> what difference it makes?

The extension of a header file has no effect on anything. You could have just as well named the file `test.mpg`, `.test` or just `test` (changing the include directive obviously), and it would have worked just as well. The extension is for the benefit of the programmer, not the toolchain.

However, it is a bad idea to name it anything other than .h, .hpp or whatever is your convention. If you name it .mpg, people will think that it is a video, and not realising that it is a header file, try to play it in a media player. If you name it .cpp, people will think that it is a source file and may attempt to compile it or maybe add definitions into it.

Including a file with the preprocessor is technically just copying contents of one file into another. Nothing more and nothing less. Everything else about them is just convention.

> In makefile, when specifying source file, Can I give my source files with any extension(.fsfs, .xxx) rather than .cpp extension

Technically yes, however compilers usually use the source file extension to detect the language which they will fail to do in this case, so you would have to specify it explicitly.

Answer (score 3):

It changes nothing. It's just a convention whether you use a *.h or *.cpp or *.asdasd suffix, as long as it doesn't get compiled by itself.

Some projects use the .hxx extension for header files and .cc for source file.

Please, for the good of fellow programmers you'll work with, stick to common conventions and don't put header code in .cpp files.

Comment: In that case Can I add anything(file with any extension) to the make file with a proper cpp code inside?

Comment: @infiniteloop sorry, can you rephrase that? I'm not sure I understand.

Comment: In makefile, when specifying source file, Can I give my source files with any extension(.fsfs, .xxx) rather than .cpp extension (content in the file would be valid cpp content and same in both the cases)

Comment: @infiniteloop You can, but as explained by user2079303, don't do that, it's confusing.

Answer (score 2):

`#include` just does a copy-n-paste of the file you include into the current file. What the file is named doesn't matter one bit - you can name it "foo.exe" if you like; as long as it contains valid source-code in the context where it is included all is well (but please don't use unconventional names, you'll just confuse people).

Comment: (but please don't)

Comment: @BoundaryImposition Agreed. Very much.